# How can I get my mvc partial view layout to display in two columns instead of one using kendo mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Could use some help understanding divs and layouts in a mvc view

I have a partial view

```
@model Hybridinator.WebUI.Models.DatabaseModel
<br />

    if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.database_name != null && Model.database_name != "")
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="databaselabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_name, "Database")</div>
                <div id="databaseedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_name)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="databaseserverlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_server, "Database Server")</div>
                <div id="databaseserveredit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_server)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="databaseusernamelabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_username, "Database Username")</div>
                <div id="databaseusernameedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_username)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="databasepasswordlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_password, "Database Password")</div>
                <div id="databasepasswordedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_password)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaselabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_name, "History Database")</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_name)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaseserverlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_server, "History Database Server")</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseserveredit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_server)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaseusernamelabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_username, "History Database Username")</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseusernameedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_username)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabasepasswordlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_password, "History Database Password")</div>
                <div id="histdatabasepasswordedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_password)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="sqltypelabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.sql_type_pk, "Sql Type")</div>
                <div id="sqltypeddl">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.sql_type)</div>
            </div>
            <br />
            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("buttonEditDatabase")
                    .Content("Edit")
                    .Events(events => { events.Click("editDatabase"); })
            )
        }

}
```

when it is displayed it looks like this...

[image]

what I would like is for it to actually be in two columns and look like this

[image]

Any advice on how to do this...or maybe a good tutorial on using divs in views to accomplish layout would be appreciated.

Comment: Style your elements using CSS [Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and/or [floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). And why does you partial have a `<form>` element? (it doesn't contain any controls!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem using the Kendo().Splitter() control.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter().Name("VerticalDatabaseInfoSplit").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px;" }).Panes(pane =>
        {
            pane.Add()
                .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "left-pane" })
                .Scrollable(false)
                .Collapsible(false)
                .Resizable(false)
                .Scrollable(false)
                .Size("350px")
                .Content(
                @<div style="margin:3%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="databasedisplaylabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_name, "Database", new { style = "width: 200px"})</div>
                        <div id="databasedisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_name, new { style = "width: 250px" })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="databaseserverdisplaylabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_server, "Database Server", new { style = "width: 200px" })</div>
                        <div id="databaseserverdisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_server, new { style = "width: 250px" })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="databaseusernamedisplaylabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_username, "Database Username", new { style = "width: 200px" })</div>
                        <div id="databaseusernamedisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_username, new { style = "width: 250px" })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="databasepassworddisplaylabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_password, "Database Password", new { style = "width: 200px" })</div>
                        <div id="databasepassworddisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_password, new { style = "width: 250px" })</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="sqltypedisplaylabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.sql_type_pk, "Sql Type", new { style = "width: 200px" })</div>
                        <div id="sqltypeddl">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.sql_type, new { style = "width: 200px" })</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                );
            pane.Add()
           .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "right-pane" })
           .Scrollable(false)
           .Collapsible(false)
           .Resizable(false)
           .Size("350px")
           .Scrollable(false)
           .Content(
        @<div style="margin: 1%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaselabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_name, "History Database", new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_name, new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaseserverlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_server, "History Database Server", new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseserveredit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_server, new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabaseusernamelabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_username, "History Database Username", new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
                <div id="histdatabaseusernameedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_username, new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="histdatabasepasswordlabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_password, "History Database Password", new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
                <div id="histdatabasepasswordedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_password, new { style = "width: 300px" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <br /><br />
                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                        .Name("buttonEditDatabase")
                        .Content("Edit")
                        .Events(events => { events.Click("editDatabase"); })
                    )
                </div>
            </div>
                );
        }))
```

Answer (score 2):

Are u using bootstrap? then the unswer is to use div wrapper with special class 'col-md-6'. Refer to getbootstrap.com for more information.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="databaselabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.database_name, "Database")</div>
    <div id="databaseedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.database_name, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
  </div>
  ....
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="histdatabaselabel">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.hist_database_name, "History Database")</div>
    <div id="histdatabaseedit">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.hist_database_name, new { @class ="form-control" })</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: sorry should have indicated..not using bootstrap..using kendo

Comment: no Kendo UI or ASP.NET MVC will help u with your problem, u need an CSS Framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [columnizer jquery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/). helpful when amount of rows is dynamic

wrap your form-group elements in some div and apply plugin to it.

for example:

```
$('.wrapper').columnize({ columns: 2 });
```